# How do I stop this text from overlapping the background?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When my website is in normal view, it looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEa6G.png)

However when the width of the browser window shrinks [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8V9n.png) appears. Fyi this is not the mobile view, this is still the desktop view with a smaller width.

`Code:` https://jsfiddle.net/y5cr1d84/

Comment: You need to show your code here, not images of what is happening.

Comment: what do you want it to do?

Comment: What is your parent containers code? Or maybe just provide a codepen.

Comment: @Mason I want the gray and red part extend, but have the text cut off if the width is to short, to ensure that there is no vertical sidebar

Comment: @5Flux use `overflow-x: hidden;` Edit: wait I think I misunderstood you, do you want the text to wrap around and make the container taller?

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden;` works perfectly. [link](https://i.imgur.com/XN1QmQS.png)

Comment: what did you mean by wanting the "gray and red part extend". Using `overflow-x: hidden` doesn't make it extend in any way.

Comment: i thought i wanted that, but I was too afraid that it would create vertical sliders. however this option works, so thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: Make your code text wrap:

```
#codebox > pre{
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```css
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500);
.codingbox {
  padding-top: 20vh;
}

#codebox {
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.codeheader {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
}

#codeheader {
  background-color: #CD3333;
}

#codebox > pre{
   white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class>
  <div class="codingbox">
    <div class="codeheader" id="codeheader">Code</div>
    <div id="codebox">
      <pre><code data-language="css">
&lt;form name="contact"&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
&lt;label&gt;Name &lt;input type="text" name="name" />&lt;/label&gt;
&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
&lt;label&gt;Email &lt;input type="email" name="email" />&lt;/label&gt;
&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
&lt;button type="submit">Send&lt;/button&gt;
&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/form&gt;
                      </code></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Option 2: Give your container a fixed width:

```
.codingbox {
    width: 450px;
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500);
.codingbox {
  padding-top: 20vh;
}

#codebox {
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: Courier, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 6px 6px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.codeheader {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
}

#codeheader {
  background-color: #CD3333;
}

#codebox>pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.codingbox {
    width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<div class>
  <div class="codingbox">
    <div class="codeheader" id="codeheader">Code</div>
    <div id="codebox">
      <pre><code data-language="css">
&lt;form name="contact"&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
&lt;label&gt;Name &lt;input type="text" name="name" />&lt;/label&gt;
&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
&lt;label&gt;Email &lt;input type="email" name="email" />&lt;/label&gt;
&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;
&lt;button type="submit">Send&lt;/button&gt;
&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/form&gt;
                      </code></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: all of these fold the text into the next line, which ruin the effect of the code box

Answer (score 0):

You should add `white-space: pre-line` to break the spaces inside your code section. https://jsfiddle.net/z1f8rb56/

Comment: or perhaps [one of the other values](https://beta.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)